# multiple definition in header file

Tags: c++, header-files

Given this code sample:

**complex.h :**

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

#include <iostream>

class Complex
{
public:
   Complex(float Real, float Imaginary);

   float real() const { return m_Real; };

private:
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Complex& Cplx);

   float m_Real;
   float m_Imaginary;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Complex& Cplx) {
   return o << Cplx.m_Real << " i" << Cplx.m_Imaginary;
}
#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

**complex.cpp :**

```
#include "complex.h"

Complex::Complex(float Real, float Imaginary) {
   m_Real = Real;
   m_Imaginary = Imaginary;
}
```

**main.cpp :**

```
#include "complex.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   Complex Foo(3.4, 4.5);
   std::cout << Foo << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

When compiling this code, I get the following error:

```
multiple definition of operator<<(std::ostream&, Complex const&)
```

I've found that making this function `inline` solves the problem, but I don't understand why. Why does the compiler complain about multiple definition? My header file is guarded (with `#define COMPLEX_H`).

And, if complaining about the `operator<<` function, why not complain about the `public real()` function, which is defined in the header as well?

And is there another solution besides using the `inline` keyword?

Comment: You can also make the function static. The inline specifier is commonly used to force a function to have internal linkage.

Comment: @Akanksh, actually that's exactly what "inline" is for.

Comment: @Akanksh: Using `static` for this purpose is deprecated in C++. `static` has been completely replaced by anonymous namespaces, although in this particular case, `inline` is the way to go.

Comment: @Akanksh: That invites ODR violations by giving the same name (`operator<<`) different meanings in different translation units.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The problem is that the following piece of code is a definition, not a declaration:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Complex& Cplx) {
   return o << Cplx.m_Real << " i" << Cplx.m_Imaginary;
}
```

You can either mark the function above and make it "inline" so that  multiple translation units may define it:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Complex& Cplx) {
   return o << Cplx.m_Real << " i" << Cplx.m_Imaginary;
}
```

Or you can simply move the original definition of the function to the "complex.cpp" source file.

The compiler does not complain about "real()" because it is implicitly inlined (any member function whose body is given in the class declaration is interpreted as if it had been declared "inline"). The preprocessor guards prevent your header from being included more than once from a single translation unit ("*.cpp" source file"). However, both translation units see the same header file. Basically, the compiler compiles "main.cpp" to "main.o" (including any definitions given in the headers included by "main.cpp"), and the compiler separately compiles "complex.cpp" to "complex.o" (including any definitions given in the headers included by "complex.cpp"). Then the linker merges "main.o" and "complex.o" into a single binary file; it is at this point that the linker finds two definitions for a function of the same name. It is also at this point that the linker attempts to resolve external references (e.g. "main.o" refers to "Complex::Complex" but does not have a definition for that function... the linker locates the definition from "complex.o", and resolves that reference).

Answer (score 6):

Move implementation to complex.cpp

Right now after including this file implementation is being compiled to every file. 
Later during linking there's a obvious conflict because of duplicate implementations.

::real() is not reported because it's inline implicitly (implementation inside class definition)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem, even after my source and header file were correct.

It turned out Eclipse was using stale artifacts from a previous (failed) build.

To fix, use `Project > Clean` then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to designating a function *definition* in a header file as `inline` is to define it as `static`. This will also avoid the multiple definition error.

Comment: That makes the functions have internal linkage - different from `inline`.  In particular, this will cause ODR violations (ill-formed NDR) if an inline function tries to call them in different translation units.