# 'Multiple Definition' error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a `User` class, however I'm getting an error output whenever I try to compile this code:

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <string>

/* Classes */
class User {
    std::string username, password;

    public:
    void set_user_username (std::string);
    void set_user_password (std::string);
};

// Sets the User's username
void User::set_user_username (std::string input) {
    username = input;
}

// Sets the User's password
void User::set_user_password (std::string input) {
    password = input;
}

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

> multiple definition of `User::set_user_username(std::string)'

Any clue why it's giving me this error message?

Comment: Is all of that code in the header file without guards? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Nope. I put guards in. Updated the code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah. I see now! How would I be able to include this header file in another .cpp file without it conflicting like that?

Comment: @JennyLee: see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the body of the `set_user_username()` and `set_user_password()` methods inside of the header file, but outside of the class declaration.  As such, if you include this header file in multiple translation units, regardless of the use of header guards, the linker is going to see multiple object files defining the same methods and fail due to a violation of the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

You need to either:

- move the definitions to their own translation unit, and then link that unit in your project:

  Login.h

  ```
  #ifndef LOGIN_H
  #define LOGIN_H

  #include <string>

  /* Classes */
  class User {
      std::string username, password;

  public:
      void set_user_username (std::string);
      void set_user_password (std::string);
  };

  #endif // LOGIN_H
  ```

  Login.cpp

  ```
  #include "Login.h"

  // Sets the User's username
  void User::set_user_username (std::string input) {
      username = input;
  }

  // Sets the User's password
  void User::set_user_password (std::string input) {
      password = input;
  }
  ```
- move the definitions inline inside the class declaration:

  Login.h

  ```
  #ifndef LOGIN_H
  #define LOGIN_H

  #include <string>

  /* Classes */
  class User {
      std::string username, password;

  public:
      void set_user_username (std::string input) {
          username = input;
      }

      void set_user_password (std::string input) {
          password = input;
      }
  };

  #endif // LOGIN_H
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The definitions are in the header without the inline keyword.  Use the inline keyword or move the definitions into a .cpp file.

```
// Sets the User's username
inline void User::set_user_username (std::string input) {
    username = input;
}

// Sets the User's password
inline void User::set_user_password (std::string input) {
    password = input;
}
```

[multiple definition in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727582/multiple-definition-in-header-file)