# I get this error for having defined a function twice

Tags: c++, class, oop, enums

**Error**:

```
CMakeFiles\Final_Project_2nd.dir/objects.a(Tab.cpp.obj): In function `Z8Type2IntNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE':
C:/Users/Andrea/CLionProjects/Final_Project_2nd/Utils.hpp:37: multiple definition of `Type2Int(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles\Final_Project_2nd.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):C:/Users/Andrea/CLionProjects/Final_Project_2nd/Utils.hpp:37: first defined here
```

I've created a header `Utils.hpp` with two `enum`s and two functions and I included it wherever I needed to use these things:

```
enum Types {
    OptionInt,
    OptionFloat,
    [...]
    OptionInvalid
};
enum Commands {
    CommandCreate = OptionInvalid + 1,
    CommandDrop,
    [...]
    CommandInvalid
};
Types Type2Int(string type){
    if(type == "int") return OptionInt;
    if(type == "float") return OptionFloat;
    [...]
    return OptionInvalid;
}
Commands Command2Int(string command){
    if(command == "CREATE") return CommandCreate;
    if(command == "DROP") return CommandDrop;
    [...]
    return CommandInvalid;
}
```

Comment: declare these functions as `inline`

Comment: Why is my question already down-voted 25 seconds after I've posted it? Is there anything wrong  with it? I didn't "make an effort" to make it work because I've literally no idea why that error is there

Comment: I guess people get frustrated when a person doesn't know the fundamentals.
This one has to do with ODR(One Definition Rule)

Comment: Thank you @Adler it worked! I've never used `inline` before, why is it necessary here?

Comment: You've declared a function in a header file. So you will get this error whenever you include this header in several compilation units(.cpp files).
To make things right, you need to either declare as `inline` or define these functions in a compilation unit

Comment: @Adler I've never been taught this topic... I've only followed 2 courses at university, but I'm studying electrical engineering... If there's a "noob" section I'll join it

Comment: just take a respectable book on C++ and go with it. To be pragmatic, I would recommend 'A Tour of C++'(by Bjarne Stroustrup)

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly do it after the exam period! Since this is not my "main" subject I may be inappropriate or I may use an imprecise language, I get it, but I'm trying my best for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the function in the header, that's the problem.
[multiple definition in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727582/multiple-definition-in-header-file)

The `inline` solution is fine, in alternative you can keep the declaration in the hpp file and implement it in a separate cpp file - which is the most 'standard' solution.